# Get the Date of an Email via AppleScript

Tags: email, date, applescript, geektool

I am currently trying to customize an AppleScript that is reading the unread Mails in the Inbox.
That basically works fine except the fact, that I can#T manage to get the date of the mails.

After  about 2 hours of googling around I found out that the Variable I need should be receivedate or deliverydate, but when trying to use one of these I get an error like this:

```
"...receivedate of id... cannot be converted to Type reference..."
```

Someone's got an Idea, how I can convert this?

And this is my current code:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set processList to (name of every process)
end tell
if processList contains "Mail" then
tell application "Mail"
    if (unread count of inbox) > 0 then
        set messageList to (messages of inbox) whose read status is false
        set output to "Mails:" & return & return & ""
        repeat with itemNum from 1 to (unread count of inbox)
            set itemDate to (receivedate of item itemNum of messageList)
            set output to output & itemDate & " - " & (extract name from sender of item itemNum of messageList) & return & subject of item itemNum of messageList & return & return
        end repeat
    end if
end tell
else
set output to "ÄpplMäil isch aus..."
end if
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term you are looking for is `date received`

```
tell application "Mail" to if running then
    if (unread count of inbox) > 0 then
        set output to "Mails:" & return & return & ""
        repeat with thisMsg in (get messages of inbox whose read status is false)
            tell thisMsg to set output to output & (date received) & " - " & (extract name from sender) & return & subject & return & return
        end repeat
    end if
else
    set output to "ÄpplMäil isch aus..."
end if
```

A quicker way to get the help you need is the Applescript dictionarie of **Mail**.
All commands, classes and properties of **Mail** are in this dictionary.

One way of opening this dictionary is to use the Open Dictionary item in the `File` menu of `AppleScript Editor`.  When you use this item, you will get a listing of the available applications that have dictionaries.  Choose `Mail` and click the Open button or use the Browse button to navigate to an unlisted application.

Another way to open a dictionary, is to make use of `AppleScript Editor's` Library window.  It's located in the `Window` menu below the Result History and Event Log History menu items.  The Library window shows a list of default applications whose dictionaries you can open with a double click.

Comment: Ah, yeah, thats indeed what I was looking for!

The same goes for the Library Window - wassearching for something like that SO hard, that I missed to have a look in the Editor itself -.-'

Thank you so much!